# Subversion repository on Amazon S3

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, amazon-s3

Is it possible to put a subversion repository on Amazon S3.

I found [SvnToS3](http://code.google.com/p/svntos3/) on google code but that project seems dead.

Answer (score 0):

I think  the document of [s3vn](http://s3vn.msigi.net/) tool will somehow help you to achieve your goal.